# Passing Variables Simplified

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a project, but I need to pass variables between functions and I do not know how. I am not very good at python at all. I just started learning it like a month ago. Anyhow I just want to know the simplest way to pass a variable between functions.

Can I just do this?

```
def a():
    variable1 = 0
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "a":
       print "Correct"
       b()

def b():
    #Variable1 should now be here also right?
    a()
```

Comment: Some pointer on "namespace" if you want to do more python: http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/ https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Answer (score 2):

Add a **parameter** to your function b.

```
def b(argument1):
   print 'This is function b(), argument1=', argument1

def a():
    # call func b, passing it 42 as an argument
    b(42)
```

- [Python Functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

---

In Python you *can* use global variables, but this is not the recommended way of doing things. Global variables should generally be avoided.

```
def b()
    print 'This is function b(), globalVar1=', globalVar1

def a()
    global globalVar1

    globalVar1 = 88

    b()
```

- [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass a variable between functions is to define the necessary function to accept an argument. [Check out functions -part in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

In your case you want to pass `variable1` to `b`. Define `b` as such:

```
def b(var):
     print var
     # Whatever else you want to do..

def a():
    variable1 = 0
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "a":
       print "Correct"
       b(variable1)
```

Your original code does not work because variables inside functions are local to those functions. Using function arguments is the correct way of doing what you want.